# How to get Keys and Values using FirebaseListAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

this code get the values and set them in listview i want to get keys to use them also, please see the image to view the database example

```
FirebaseListAdapter firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(this, String.class, R.layout.users_list, usersUrl) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View view, String base64Image, int i) {
            //((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(s);
            byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(base64Image.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap bitmap =BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);

            ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageBitmap(RoundedImageView.getCroppedBitmap(bitmap,100));



        }
    };
```

[database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VGkF.png)

Answer (score 3):

You can get the `DatabaseReference` for the current item by calling `getRef(position)`:

```
protected void populateView(View view, String base64Image, int position) {
    DatabaseReference itemRef = getRef(position);
    String itemKey = itemRef.getKey();
    ...
```